# What should we use instead of GoogleApiClient in Kotlin?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, google-api-client

As we know, GoogleApiClient is deprecated and android studio gives error when we use its library for get data from google api. what should we use instead of GoogleApiClient?

Answer (score 0):

What the documentation [says](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient):

> Use [GoogleApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApi.html) based APIs instead. See [Moving Past GoogleApiClient](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/11/moving-past-googleapiclient_21.html).

The reason is explained in that last link:

> The code is dominated by the concept of a connection, despite using the simplified "automanage" feature. A GoogleApiClient is only connected when all APIs are available and the user has signed in (when APIs require it).
>
> This model has a number of pitfalls:
>
> - Any connection failure prevents use of any of the requested APIs, but using multiple GoogleApiClient objects is unwieldy.
> - The concept of a "connection" is inappropriately overloaded. Connection failures can be result from Google Play services being missing or from authentication issues.
> - The developer has to track the connection state, because making some calls before onConnected is called will result in a crash.
> - Making a simple API call can mean waiting for two callbacks. One to wait until the GoogleApiClient is connected and another for the API call itself.
>
> ...
>
> In general, the new GoogleApi-based APIs have the following benefits:
>
> - No connection logic, calls that require a connection are queued until a connection is available. Connections are pooled when appropriate and torn down when not in use, saving battery and preventing memory leaks.
> - Sign in is completely separated from APIs that consume GoogleSignInAccount which makes it easier to use authenticated APIs throughout your app.
> - Asynchronous API calls use the new Task API rather than PendingResult, which allows for easier management and chaining.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Alexey Romanov, GoogleApi in now used instead of GoogleApiClient or it is for future?

Comment: Yes, it can be used now. Note this explanation of "deprecated" https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/deprecation/deprecation.html.

Comment: But I couldn't use GoogleApi instead of  GoogleApiClient. My app found problem.

Comment: Then ask about that problem (in a separate question). Or keep using  GoogleApiClient for now, while being aware it's deprecated and may be removed in the future.